# What Are Some Examples of Applications of LTI Systems

Tags: filters, linear-systems

I'm giving a lecture on LTI systems. I encountered some questions:

1. for a discrete LTI system H with impulse response h, is the system applied on signal x(t) equals x*h - normal discrete convolution or the cyclic convolution?
2. can you please give me some examples of useful LTI systems? such as Prewitt or Roberts edge detection, and gauss smoothing.

Thanks.

Comment: Electrical engineering is based off linear systems.

Comment: If you are _giving_ a lecture on LTI systems, I hope for the sake of your audience that you have a better grasp of the subject than your questions seem to indicate.

Comment: "give me some examples of useful LTI system". With all due respect that's a bizarre question. LTI is one of the most fundamental concepts in science and technology and it's been used extensively in creating your car,  your phone, your house, your lights, your TV, the medical equipment at your doctor's, etc.

Comment: Could you please review my answer?

Answer (score 1):

1. The normal convolution.
   The only difference is that all the frequency domain analysis is made under the assumption of periodic signal.
2. The [`Matched Filter`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matched_filter) used for estimation and detection.

Answer (score -1):

Normal convolution, because impulse and discrete convolution requires the sequence of data of lti and circular convolution requires circular data and point of origin to convolute

Lti systems are used mostly in seismology and signal processing stuff, and by stuff I mean circuits and data analyzing and field equation analyzing theories and experiments. Seismology is most affected and interestingly practical

I am a student in Vtu bti Bangalore sarjapur kodathi contact me if any doubt